# Asp.NET Chart generates image file without a filename

Tags: asp.net, charts

I am using ASP.NET Chart control.  There are many (About 10, all inside a Repeter) charts on my page.

Each chart has ImageStorageMode set to "UseImageLocation".

The problem is that each Chart control, for some reason, generates an image file without a filename, only has the .PNG extension.  And so they overwrite each other and only the last image is displayed every every on the page.

Advice ?

Answer (score 2):

I just had this issue and figured out what the issue was. The hint I got was from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/29ce1ba3-c338-41ee-b218-c78f432b2f77/delete-images-from-useimagelocation-location

It seems that the property for `Chart.ImageLocation` is slightly misleading as MSDN says

> A string value that represents the URL of the current chart image.

However this should also include a filename and I suspect you have something like this

```
Chart chart = new Chart();
chart.RenderType = RenderType.ImageTag;
chart.ImageStorageMode = ImageStorageMode.UseImageLocation;
chart.ImageLocation = "~/TempImages/";
```

This will generate an image URL like this

```
<img src="/TempImages/.png?y56r6y7f5w4r5" />
```

Change the `chart.ImageLocation` to include a filename that produces a sequence like this

```
chart.ImageLocation = "~/TempImages/ChartPicture_#SEQ(300,5)";
```

Now you'll generate images like this

```
ChartPicture_000001.png
ChartPicture_000002.png
ChartPicture_000003.png
ChartPicture_000004.png
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Did u try to set ImageUrl property.

Here is some  more information on how to use it
Also post some sample code if this does not work.

[Using ImageUrl](http://support2.dundas.com/OnlineDocumentation/WebChart2003/DundasWebChart~Dundas.Charting.WebControl.Chart~ImageUrl.html)